# Permanently set prompt to show timestamp in terminal

Tags: command-line, timestamp

I want to see the time to each command in my terminal.

When I do this command:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -n "$(date +%H:%M:%S) "
```

after I close the terminal I need to input it again.

How can I make this permanent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add this line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -n "$(date +%H:%M:%S) "'
```

Then save the file and open a new terminal and it should work as expected.